# How can I append a button at the end of ui-select and register a click event dynamically in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can I append a button at the end of ui-select dropdown and register a click event dynamically in angularjs. I need to add type ahead value on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't append a button element inside select box, you can do some css trick like [here](https://codepen.io/webrajendra/pen/VvjgYY) link to display a button an attach an event to that button.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li class="init">[SELECT]</li>
<li data-value="value 1">Option 1</li>
<li data-value="value 2">Option 2</li>
<li data-value="value 3"><button>BTN</button></li></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes this is an option but i was looking for writing custom tag for this.Is it possible??

Comment: Yes you can modify this as a directive, look https://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/  to learn about directives